# Recursively count the number of bits required to represent a number

Tags: recursion, binary

Hallo :) i wanna count the Binary numbers, with this Method

```
   private static  int helper ( int c,int zaehler){


    if (c>>1 == 1){
        return zaehler + 2;


    }else{

        return helper(c>>1,zaehler++);



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to recursively count the number of bits required to represent a number (i.e. log2)?

```
class Foo {
    private static int helper (int c, int zaehler){
        if (c == 0) {
            // Base case, c = 0 so no more bits to count
            return zaehler;
        } else {
            // c >>> 1 is the number without the LSB (assuming Java)
            return helper(c >>> 1, zaehler + 1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(helper(Integer.parseInt(args[0]), 1));
    }
}
```

Here are examples showing that it works:

```
$ java Foo 5   #  5 =   101
3
$ java Foo 15  # 15 =  1111
4
$ java Foo 16  # 16 = 10000
5
```

Comment: If c = 10, zaehler has to be 4; cause we need 4 BinaryLetter

Comment: I thought you wanted to count the bits, so that `1010b` is 2 because there are 2 `1`s. I've updated it to count the number of bits required to represent a number, so that `1010b` is 4.

Answer (score 0):

Given the clarification of what you want that you gave @thatotherguy, you can implement this without using `zaehler` and make it `public` without exposing yourself to the risk that somebody will make the initial call with an invalid second argument.

```
class TestNumBits {
   public static int numBits(int c) {
      if (c > 0) {
         return 1 + numBits(c / 2);
      }
      if (c == 0) {
         return 0;
      }
      return numBits(-c);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(numBits(Integer.parseInt(args[0])));
   }
}
```

Sample output:

```
$ java TestNumBits 3
2
$ java TestNumBits 5
3
$ java TestNumBits -5
3
$ java TestNumBits 10
4
$ java TestNumBits 16
5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bitwise operators to get the answer. Here's an exmple on Python:

```
def countBits(n):
    if n<=1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 1+countBits(n>>1)

n = int(input("Enter a number greater than -1\n> "))
bits = countBits(n)
print(f"You need {bits} bit(s) to represent number {n} ({bin(n)})")
```

Note that **this example works only with integers greater than -1**